# Use apply functions with classes

Tags: python, pandas, function, machine-learning

I have created a function 'salary'. If salary is less than 30000, it will return 0; if salary is between 30000 and 40000, it will return 1; else if it is above 40000 it will return 2.

```py
def salary(x):
    if x < 30000:
        return 0
    elif x >= 30000 and x < 40000:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

There is only one column in my dataset 'salary'. Using apply transformation I have created a new column 'salary_level' which will save values from the 'salary' function.

```py
df['salary_level'] = df['salary'].apply(salary)
df.head()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjHP4.jpg)

Now I want to do the same using classes but I'm getting error on this code:

```py
class Salary():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def sal(self):
        if self.x < 30000:
            return 0
        elif self.x >= 30000 and self.x < 40000:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2

df['salary_level'] = df.apply(sal)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX2BD.jpg)

> Error: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'x'", 'occurred at index salary')

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the class?

Comment: is this function is part of class `Salary`? if that so have construct the class first and then call the method or remove the class

Comment: You are calling the `sal` method correctly, `df['salary_level'] = df.apply(Salary().sal)`

Comment: @lefloxy that will result in error as you have provide, `x` for **init**

Comment: Off topic but your function could be reduced to `(x >= 30000) + (x >= 40000)` and remove the if branches.

Comment: @DOOM I have not tested my code but you are right, I might have forgotten to index the `salary`. `df['salary_level'] = df['salary'].apply(Salary().sal)`

Comment: @lefloxy, you still need to pass something to the `Salary.__init__` method

Comment: @lefloxy  Also how can I create an object of this class and perform the same lambda transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a method from Class such in your case try this way:

```
df['salary_level']= df['salary'].apply(lambda x : Salary(x).sal())
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Also how can I create an object of this class and perform the same lambda transformation?

Comment: @MohammedAli Sure,it is basic oops ,first you define the class object which `Salary()` and then call the method `sal()`,now the class object required an arguments `x` that is  why I applied it with `lambda` to reference the df row as arguments for the class

Comment: so what is the object in this case?